# QGIS plugin fails to read proxy credentials from authcfg

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, proxy

I'm developing a public python plugin for QGIS. To support QGIS proxy settings, I use `Qt Network`. The plugin sends HTTP requests via the `QgsNetworkAccessManager`'s `get`/`post`/`delete` methods.

To test proxy support, I set up a proxy as below (with the real host & port of course):
[image: Proxy setup]

I enter the credentials into `Basic Auth` and click `Convert to configuration`. This creates a new config and erases the entered credentials from the `Basic Auth` tab's fields.
Next, I restart QGIS, check that the created config is selected in proxy settings, run my plugin, and get a credentials input dialog:
[image: Credentials input dialog]

When I enter the credentials, it works. It also works if I keep the credentials in the `Basic Auth` tab in QGIS proxy settings. But why doesn't my plugin read the configuration?

Comment: Look at tests e.g https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/src/python/test_authmanager_proxy.py#L75 It should give you the missing clues

Comment: Thank you, @ThomasG77. It turns out the only thing I had to do was call setupDefaultProxyAndCache() explicitly on the QgsNeworkAccessManager. It's a pity it's not explained anywhere in the docs. Although, I'd expect QGIS to execute this command automatically at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the only thing I had to do was call `setupDefaultProxyAndCache()` explicitly on the `QgsNeworkAccessManager`. It's a pity it's not explained anywhere in the docs. Although, I'd expect QGIS to execute this command automatically at startup.

Thanks to ThomasG77 for giving me a clue.